# How can I handle a linq query does not return any value?

Tags: .net, database

I'm using the following script in order to find out if there is a relevant record in a table in .NET MVC.

```
Call_Info_Timings curr_cit = db.Call_Info_Timings.Where(m => m.call_id == id).FirstOrDefault();

if (curr_cit == null)
            { 
             .....
            }
```

I need to check if a record with call_id is already stored in the Call_Info_Timings table.

In case the call_id is not stored in the Call_Info_Timings table the my application stacks.

Which is the proper way to find out if a record exists or not in a table?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I'd go with `if (db.Call_Info_Timings.Any(m => m.call_id == id)) { /*Do something*/}`.

Comment: @TeodorVladutu Thank you! You can add it as an answer to accept it.